How to solve for demand?

Hi I am fairly new to these kinds of optimization problems and I am not clear how from equation (1) the authors derive the demand function for a drug j.
I mean I think they used the Lagrangian and as a budget constrain something like y_i(t)+p_j(t) x_{ji} = income of i but I wouldd like to understand the mathematical steps to reach the result. Also is there a general rule for computing the demand starting from preferences?
Thank you

This is the maximisation problem that authors have solved for each period $t$ and for every individual $i\in G_j$. For simplicity of the notation, I have removed the expression $t$ with parenthesis - $(t)$ from everywhere:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{(c_{i},x_{ij})\in\mathbb{R}^2_+}&  q_j^\gamma c_i^{1-\gamma}x_{ij}^\gamma \\ \text{s.t } & c_i+p_jx_{ij}=y_i\end{eqnarray*}
which is same as solving:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{(c_{i},x_{ij})\in\mathbb{R}^2_+}&   c_i^{1-\gamma}x_{ij}^\gamma \\ \text{s.t } & c_i+p_jx_{ij}=y_i\end{eqnarray*}
Solution to the above problem satisfy:

MRS $=\dfrac{(1-\gamma)x_{ij}}{\gamma c_i}=\dfrac{1}{p_j}$ and
$c_i+p_jx_{ij}=y_i$

Solving them for $x_{ij}$, we get the demand as:
$x_{ij}=\dfrac{\gamma y_i}{p_j}$.
